# Replace a Part of a Image with another Image - EMGU(OpenCV)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, emgucv

I am using EMGU C#.

I have a bigger image A and smaller Image B. Image A has a part that has to be replaced by Image B. Using SIFT (Scale-invariant feature transform) on Image A, I have got the homography matrix of the part needed to be replaced. Now I want to use homography matrix and replace Image B on Image A.

How can I use homography matrix and replace just Image B?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you have a single function to achieve this.

I would do the following:

```
 1) make mask image (all white pixels) and transform it using homography

 2) make bitwise or operation between destination image and the mask
    (now you masked your destination area - you have a white patch to your destination)

 3) resize your small image and transfrom it using homography matrix

 4) use bitwise and operation between destination image (has a white patch) and your transformed small image
```